# How to get chainId currently selected in walletconnect?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, json-rpc, walletconnect

I connected WalletConnect to my dApp, and it returned account address & chainId. After changing the chain on WalletConnect wallet, no event or function is called. How can I know at my dApp frontend, which chainId is currently selected in dApp?

Comment: I've noticed the `session_update` & `wc_sessionUpdate` events are not very dependable. Sometimes they'll fire, sometimes they won't. Try moving back n' forth between a few chains several times to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 5):

Check `web3.eth.getChainId()`.

You find the documentation here:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#getchainid

Also there is an EIP-1193 event in WalletConnect that tells you when the chain has been changed:

https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/web3-provider#events-eip-1193

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
window.w3 = web3
web3.eth.getChainId().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation about what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's really much simpler than what this guys is selling. I assume you are like me trying to get the chain with having a wallet connect modal. This is part of the set up with the html modal.
https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web/web3modal/html/wagmi/installation

```
    const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
        autoConnect: true,
        connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 2, chains }),
        publicClient
    });
    const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains);

    console.log(ethereumClient.getNetwork());
```

[image]
You will get information like this. I found this by randomly trying the vscode suggestions, so I can't point you to documentation. The ethereumClient.getNetwork() function works.